suspend 'bug' for ubuntu 24.04LTS
just upgraded (with great pains, and a total crash repaired by boot repair) to Ubuntu 24.04LTS (20.04LTS, to 22.04LTS, to 23.10, to 24.04LTS).
however, when I run 'suspend', it suspends but won't restore ~ just hangs... BUT, if at boot up when I goto the grub sub menu to choose to boot using 5.15.0-105.115 generic rather than 6.8.0-31 generic, the suspend/resume works fine.
Also, (side note only) seems the problem with losing my build-in PCI wifi upon resume has been 'fixed' with 24.04LTS using the 5.15.0-105.115 generic as it resumes and the PCI wifi is still running - time after time so far :-D
**UPDATE - just got the 'new' 6.8.0-36.36 kernel - it ALSO won't resume after standby (to ram)... sticking with 5.15.0-105.115 :-| (come on, why can't they get this right?!?)
***UPDATE - just got the 'new' 6.8.0-38.38 kernel - it ALSO won't resume after standby (to ram), and jury still 'out' even if it did resume on whether it'd trash my PCI WiFi like 20.04LTS did after it resumed... sticking with 5.15.0-105.115... note that it won't restore after hibernation with ANY of these kernels (a whole 'nother level of issues...)... same computer, different boot for WIN7, suspend/hibernate/PCI wifi has NO problems, so shouldn't be "some hardware problem", eh?
****UPDATE - just got the 'new' 6.8.0-39.39 kernel - it ALSO won't resume after standby (to ram), and jury still 'out' even if it did resume on whether it'd trash my PCI WiFi like 20.04LTS did after it resumed... sticking with 5.15.0-105.115... side note: tried new 6.9.11 (with 911 hopeful?) but it is worse than the 6.8.0's
===> just got the new 6.10.3-061003-generic kernel and it DOES suspend/resume AND seems to be leaving my PCI wifi alone (hibernate doesn't work, but I think I have to change the format from 20.04 to 24.04 requirements...). only thing is, once booted, and only on the 1st suspend, the resume takes about 3-5 minutes ~ but all suspends after that resume in  only a few seconds.
Soooo happy :-D

Does this answer your question? Uninstall specific kernel version and How to I prevent Ubuntu from kernel version upgrade and notification?

looks like I just need to use my work around w/older kernel for now, and wait and hope that the next updated kernel after 6.8.0-31 fixes this suspend issue... patience is one of the hardest virtues ;-)

I had to lock my kernel on my Ubuntu 18.04LTS machine a long time ago - updated ones kept going from one break to another on things, so locked the one that didn't break anything... but now updates keep trying to delete it but can't as it's locked ~ update goes into this funny loop:-\

I had exactly the same issue on ThinkPad x260, Ubuntu 24.04, fully encrypted SSD. I updated to 6.9.9 from mainline and the issue disappeared. I have not tried other kernels, so I don't know, in which version it got fixed.

Added 6.9.9 via mainline, never resumed from suspend... useless as is all the other 6.9 kernels ~ sticking to 5.15.0-105 generic as it resumes and the PCI wifi is still running - but it won't restore from hibernate like my 20.04LTS did (but 20.04LTS would crash my PCI wifi resuming from standby :-\ )
This is all such a mess... same laptop w/WIN7 suspends/hibernates/PCI wifi fine! (just sayin')

I have the same issue in lenevo legion r7000 notebook. As a simple workaroud, I changed all "suspend" to "lock" in /etc/systemd/logind.conf

...so, which 'same issue' got worked around - wifi getting killed upon resuming, standby not resuming, or hibernate not restoring?

ALSO, the "/etc/systemd/logind.conf" file is all hashed-out (#) so are 'inactive'... editing them won't change anything if they're just 'comments' with a # leading the line... weird that it made any workaround!

===> just got the new 6.10.3-061003-generic kernel and it DOES suspend/resume AND seems to be leaving my PCI wifi alone (hibernate doesn't work, but I think I have to change the format from 20.04 to 24.04 requirements...). only thing is, once booted, and only on the 1st suspend, the resume takes about 3-5 minutes ~ but all suspends after that resume in only a few seconds. Soooo happy :-D

Note that "6.10.3-061003-generic" is NOT a stock Ubuntu kernel and is instead a mainline kernel (see here for details on how to tell the difference). Mainline kernels are risky to use (as they can break your machine) compared to stock Ubuntu kernels. See here for further explanation.

In my case
journalctl -b| grep -i suspend
was mentioning "nouveau" (the root of all evils on earth :)) so I blacklisted the nouveau graphical kernel driver with the
modeprobe.blacklist=nouveau
line added in the booting menu (press 'e' for editing) on the 'linux' line et voilà.
