Can't login after suspend on Ubuntu 24.04
My laptop is Lenovo IdeaPad Flex 5 with AMD Ryzen 7 5700U with Radeon Graphics × 16. I got the issue on the previous non LTS version of Ubuntu 23.10.
If I close the laptop, or it suspends in any other way, I can't login anymore. Display manager (simple gdm3, though I was trying to get other display managers before noticing the problem) just stucks cause if I try to type the password, it gets erased after 2-3 letters and says "incorrect password" or something. When I try to access tty, it starts to shows a lot of errors: 
But I noticed that not always it shows this error messages, they may differ. Also after display manager being stuck, I can't turn laptop off or reboot or do anything, so I have to turn it off from power button.

https://askubuntu.com/questions/1513210/suspend-bug-for-ubuntu-24-04lts  <Does this help your problem?
